# why type is not narrowing down when using intersection on union

Tags: typescript

```
type X = { a: 1; b: number } | { a: 2; b: string };
declare const foo: X & { a: 1 };
foo.b.toFixed(0);
//    ~~~~~~~
// Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

I expected that making intersection of `X` and `{ a: 1 }` would wipe out  the `{ a: 2, … }` part, so that foo would be effectively just `{ a: 1; b: number }`

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the way intersections work, an intersection means that the resulting type has to statify all members of the intersection, regardless if that is in fact possible or not.

What you are looking for is the `Extract` conditional type

```
type X = { a: 1; b: number } | { a: 2; b: string };
declare const foo: Extract< X, { a: 1 }>
foo.b.toFixed(0);
```